# EditText in ListView is giving nextFocus after enter key pressed

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-listview

I have a ListView subclass that display rows that each contain an `EditText` and a `TextView`.
When I touch the `EditText` it's gaining focus (good), the user type the information I want, and type the `KEYCODE_ENTER` to launch the `onEditorAction()` method from the `OnEditorActionListener interface`. On that method I'm dismissing the keyboard with this

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

All other EditText updates accordingly to the input change.
(all good so far).

BUT
After all that the orange focus is passed up to the next focus (the following row).
I would want to remove this behaviour in this case, but still want the user to have the ability to navigate from one to an other using up and down key.

So my question is:
How and where can I remove the focus of an `EditText` that is in a row of a `ListView`?

`Note that:`
I've try using `aView.clearFocus();` in the `onEditorAction()` on the EditText that is giving the focus to the next one. (don't work)
I've try using `thatListView.clearFocus();`, but as expected it didn't worked.

and if there is no easy way I'm planning to go row by row and child by child to do a `v.clearFocus()`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onEditorAction()`, return `true` to tell that you have consumed the action.

Comment: I don't know why I was sure that that had made my app crash in the past and over looked that option.